# What is the purpose of Woocommerce Rest Api wrapper

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

Please help understanding what's the purpose of woocommerce rest api wrapper.

Since we can access the Woocommerce Rest Api directly by calling endpoints from front end framework like reat/angular, what's the purpose for different Woocommerce Rest Api wrapper like for python, node.js ,php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose is providing, supported way (by woocommerce team), for servers/apps on those languages to interact with the woocommerce store.

Examples:

- Aliexpress web scraper in python to collect the latest products and publish them to your woocommerce store.
- Node.js bitcoin client to track bitcoin blockchain for payments received on store address and update orders accordingly.
- Integrate your POS in Java to the woocommerce store.

I hope this explains a little bit.
;-)